# Is it possible to delegate celery tasks and block until all is processed?

Tags: django, celery

I have this task:

```
@app.task(name='somesmalltask')
def some_small_task(some_input):
   some_list = []
   #do something to some_list
   return some_list
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
all_results = map(lambda x: some_small_task.delay(x), inputs)
#do stuff later to all_results
```

but instead of returning the celery task, I would like to actually get the result.

Would I have to do something like this for every task id?

```
result = some_small_task.AsyncResult(task_id)
result.get()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to start multiple tasks as a group, you could do something like this:

```
>>> job = group([
...             add.subtask((2, 2)),
...             add.subtask((4, 4)),
...             add.subtask((8, 8)),
...             add.subtask((16, 16)),
...             add.subtask((32, 32)),
... ])
>>> result = job.apply_async()
>>> result.join()
[4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
```

This processes the tasks simultaneously and returns the result using join() to wait for the last task to end.

More information about groups and other workflows [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups).

Comment: So based off this I decided to go with the chord approach. Thanks!